# What is the proper way to convert .flac files to 320 kBit/sec .mp3?

Tags: avconv

My latest challenge is finding out the correct way to convert several .flac files to 320k .mp3's. Does anyone know how to do this, maybe with `avconv`, without using an elaborate python script, decompressing the files to .wav first, or any other complicated scheme?

Comment: Yes, `avconv` is the new implementation of the soon-to-be-deprecated `ffmpeg`.

Comment: No sign of deprecation, really. [FFmpeg is stable, good, and very much alive](http://www.ffmpeg.org/index.html).

Comment: wow, the first comment really is a bad one that hasn't aged properly. 2023 and ffmpeg is still maintained. [link](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all you must make sure that it's installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

It should have lame and flac codecs, now is just create a bash script to finish the job:

```
$ cat > flac2mp3
```

Here the shell will wait for your commands, copy and paste this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
[[ $# == 0 ]] && set -- *.flac
for f; do
  avconv -i "$f" -qscale:a 0 "${f[@]/%flac/mp3}"
done
```

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Make your script executable `chmod +x flac2mp3`. Now go you can use it like this:

```
./flac2mp3 /path/with/all/my/flacs/*.flac
```

You can also copy the script to somewhere in your `PATH` and then `cd` to the directory with the flacs and execute it.

---

With regards to the following parameter used above:

```
-qscale:a 0
```

will not actually give you a exact *320k* file, although it is probably the best setting to use anyway. The suggested settings actually give a target bitrate of 245 kbits/s with a range of 220-260. If you really wanted 320k mp3s you would have to go to CBR and use:

```
-c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k
```

but you would need great ears to notice the difference...

Reference:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_Flac_to_Mp3#With_FFmpeg

Answer (score 5):

For Single File i use this and its work perfect for me.

```
avconv -i [FileName.flac] -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k [FileName.mp3]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a quite old thread, but I have had a similar task, so I created a little tool for converting FLAC to MP3.
(Raspberry pi 3, with OSMC)
Maybe someone will find this with the same search, that I did.

https://github.com/erdnuesse/flac-to-mp3

Features:

- Multithreaded
- preserves FLAC tags
- preserve relative directory structure
- does not delete, does not overwrite

It consists of 2 scripts, the first starts the given number of worker-instances (one for each core, or how many you want). While the second does the work.

It's based on avconv (my OSMC has 4 cores, but does not support ffmpeg out-of-the-box, so, meh, whatever.)

It's still running, so I hope, there will be no major setbacks.

Regards, 
Kay

Answer (score 1):

This script will convert all the files in the current directory to mp3 or just about any file extension you wish from just about any audio video filetype.

I've named the script mp423 because it's easy to remember and common filetypes although you can convert any type.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for f in *."$1"; do
 mplayer "$f" -novideo -ao pcm:file=tmp.wav
 lame -V 0 -q 0 tmp.wav "${f/.$1/.$2}"
 rm -f tmp.wav
done
```

Here's a use example. Save the script to your home directory and don't forget to make it executable. There is no need to provide any filename or path. Just `cd` into the directory where the files are and then run the script like this:

```
~/mp423 flac mp3
```

Another example converting all mp4 files in a directory to mp3:

```
~/mp423 mp4 mp3
```

Convert all mp4 to m4a:

```
~/mp423 mp4 m4a
```

This comes in handy when you have an entire directory full of files you need to convert.

If you only have one or two files you want to convert, just make a directory to run the files in.

Also, does not delete the original files.

Comment: obligatory [do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @qwr Yeah, this was a while ago. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, I used to use `avconv` or `ffmpeg` but `mplayer` with `lame` is so much faster. Although it decompresses to `wav` first, it's not complicated considering how much time this saves when converting a large number of files or even a single large file. Not to mention the cool output that shows your progress.

Comment: `ffmpeg` is fast enough for me (it runs at about 50-60x)

Comment: @qwr I use the highest quality options with `ffmpeg` so that may be why it is so slow (I do have great ears).

Answer (score 0):

This [flac2mp3.sh](https://github.com/patrodyne/patrodyne-scripts/tree/master/flac2mp3) script uses `ffmpeg` to convert a folder tree of FLAC files into another folder tree of MP3 files. Cover art is included, when present. You can set a `CORES` variable to create background jobs to convert several files at a time.

Comment: If that link dies this answer will no longer be useful. Can you please post the steps here to future-proof your answer?